# Play framework and javascript Assets router

Tags: javascript, playframework

I am using Play 2 framework with Scala.

I want to use `@routes.Assets.at(...)` in my Javascript to get the path to my assets. But the framework does not compile contents in the `assets` directory.

Is it possible? Or any alternative?

Comment: Have you looked at ScalaJavascriptRouting? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting

Comment: Yes, that's helpful. But I think [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/-BLgG7R68sI/kUn_6sd5VWcJ) is better.

Comment: If you figured it out, consider answering the question yourself ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
# in the controller, Scala code
def jsRouterGen = Action {
  Ok(
    Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRouter")(
     routes.javascript.Assets.at // IntelliJ will tell you this is wrong, but it you are right :)
    )
  ).as("text/javascript")
}

# in html template
# add in <head>
<script src='@routes.Application.jsRouterGen'></script>
<!-- other js that needs this router come after -->

# in your js
jsRouter.controllers.Assets.at('/use/it/like/in/html/template');
```

Note the two pairs:

- **jsRouterGen**: this defines the js router code
- **jsRouter**: it is the name of this router you will use in js code

Change them as you like, but make sure they match.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript file placed in `assets` directory is not compiled, but view wchich includes it is! So you can declare global JS var before including the JS and than in JS use this var, like:

```
<script>
    var myPathToSomeAction = '@routes.MyController.myAction()';
    var someImgPath = '@routes.Assets.at("images/some-img.jpg")';
</script>
<script src='@routes.Assets.at("js/myscript.js")'></script>
```

so in your JS you can use it i.e. like:

```
 var imgMarkup = '<img src="' + someImgPath + '" alt="" />';
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is the old way to solve this kind of problem. Creating a client-side router function is more reliable.